# reticulate: python 2 works, python 3 does not

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, reticulate, rgee

I am trying to get `rgee` properly installed for which python is a requirement. I have both an old version of python (2.7) and a new version (3.10) installed on my Mac running Big Sur OS. Installed via homebrew.

I can set the location correctly for python in reticulate using

```
use_python(Sys.which("python3"))
```

But when I try something simple like

```
np <- reticulate::import("numpy", convert = FALSE)
```

I get the error

```
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Running the same code when using python 2.7 (after restarting r session etc.)

```
use_python(Sys.which("python"))
```

works, with warnings of EOL

```
Warning message:
In py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython, config$pythonhome,  :
  Python 2 reached EOL on January 1, 2020. Python 2 compatability be removed in an upcoming reticulate release.
```

**How can I use the up-to-date version of python and still have reticulate running properly?**

Comment: missing python modules (in your case numpy) are installed via `pip` command.  you will need to ensure your python distribution has pip and use it to install numpy.

Comment: can I use ```py_install("numpy")``` in R?

Comment: I have tried the code in comment above and ```pip3 install numpy``` in terminal. After restarting the R session I am still not able to import numpy. Both confirmed installation.

Comment: Solved. Needed to use RStudio>preferences>python to select the correct location of python in the python interpreter. All worked after that.

Comment: @Nebulloyd  I suspect that this question has been asked and answered in the SO or Google universes. Can you do a search and then delete if that is so? If you cannot find a duplicate, then you can provide code and process documentation in an answer.

Comment: you can choose your python environmnet from within reticulate, though this feature broke with reticulate 1.23. so if you want to have a bit more flexibility/multiple python (for example from having both qgis and arcgis installed, or either of them + a standalone python distribution) installations i recommend using reticulate 1.22.